# Non-greedy mode in Python re module

Tags: python, regex

For some reason, I have to use the non-greedy mode of the regex in Python.
Here is the code(which might look a bit weird to you):

```
import re
# the string
s = u"<n-0><LBRACKET-1><eng-2><RBRACKET-3><n-4><n-5><v-6><n-7><m-8><GRAM-9><PU-10><n-11><LBRACKET-12><n-13><n-14><RBRACKET-15><m-16><GRAM-17>"
# the pattern
p = ur"(?P<name>(?:<n-\d+>)+(<LBRACKET-\d+>.*?<RBRACKET-\d+>)?)(?P<amount><m-\d+>)(?P<measure><GRAM-\d+>)"
tmp = re.search(p, s).group()
```

The result is the whole string `s`, but I want the result to be `<n-7><m-8><GRAM-9>` and `<n-11><LBRACKET-12><n-13><n-14><RBRACKET-15><m-16><GRAM-17>`

I think it is something to do with the non-greedy mode of regex. Could anybody point out where I am being wrong?

Comment: Why do you expect the RegEx will find `<n-7><m-8><GRAM-9>`?

Comment: @thefourtheye The question has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
p = ur"(?P<name>(?:<n-\d+>)+(<LBRACKET-\d+>((?<!RBRACKET).)*?<RBRACKET-\d+>)?)(?P<amount><m-\d+>)(?P<measure><GRAM-\d+>)"
```

Explanation: the problem with your original pattern is the catch-all fragment `.*?` between `LBRACKET` and `RBRACKET`. Yes, it's non-greedy, but greediness only applies when the engine has a choice between two or more matches. In your pattern, there's no choice, because there's only one `RBRACKET` followed by `<m...>`. Therefore, it matches `<n-0><LBRACKET-1>...<RBRACKET-15>` and doesn't look any further there because it's a valid (and shortest) match. By adding a negative lookbehind, we explicitly tell the engine that the `.*?` shouldn't contain `RBRACKET` thus forcing it to try more combinations.

Comment: Why use the `*?` when we have already use the negative lookbehind? I am still confused...

Comment: @QingchaoKong: in  this specific case it doesn't matter, but yes, it should be "R", not "L"

Comment: We still have use the non-greedy mode, so we still use `*?`, right?

Comment: @QingchaoKong: not necessarily - if you omit the question mark, the result would be the same. Again, this is because the engine has no choice here.